# Google oauth with custom URI-scheme redirect_uri using system browsers

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Google just changed their oauth model to the new specification:

[Modernizing OAuth interactions in Native Apps for Better Usability and Security](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html)

I am trying to follow (specifically section 7 of) the ietf "draft-ietf-oauth-native-apps-09" linked in the above blog, and also this reference from google:

[OAuth 2.0 for Mobile & Desktop Apps](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps)

The issue I have encountered is that the custom uri-scheme behavior varies across browsers, and in some cases does not work as expected. In Firefox, which maybe be the default system browser, the app actually open inside Firefox, embedded - it does not return to the app it embeds the app in the browser, while the app from which the authentication flow was started remains open.

In chrome, it correctly redirects back to the app, however the chrome page with the authentication confirmation page remains open and does not close, which could be confusing to users.

**How can I make sure that the oauth provider will always redirect to my app (without the browser embedding it), and close the tab or window which had the authentication flow open?**